# Use PEG.js generated parser to beautify code

Tags: peg, pegjs

I want to create a formatter/linter for a custom program language and was reading about it but seems that im missing something.

Was looking/playing with `PEG.js` and seems that it will do the work. Ive wrote a small parser and when ran - it correctly returns the syntax tree (`AST`)

And the main question now is: how to use the generated parser to create (for example) a `VSCode`/`Atom`/`CodeMirror`/etc. extension(s) that will beautify/format the code?

Is this the right approach in general? (using a parser or need to write specific parsers for each tool)

Comment: To beautify the code, you'd take your syntax tree and convert it back into well formatted code. Whether or not it's the best tool, or how to do that in a particular code editor, is a too broad a question for Stack Overflow, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautifying code is basically just converting the AST back into code, throwing away the original white space and replacing it with the desired formatting.

The following grammar converts a list of case-insensitive `a` characters into an array:

```
Expression = _ array:( a:"a"i _ {return a} )+ _ {return array}
_ = [ \t\n]*
```

So given this input:

```
aa
aaaAa

a
```

You get this output:

```
[
   "a",
   "a",
   "a",
   "a",
   "a",
   "A",
   "a",
   "a"
]
```

To "beautify" this list, you'd simply convert the array back into a list, except with a more regular spacing:

```
result.join(" ");
// produces "a a a a a A a a", which is syntactically identical
```